# AJAX PHP FormData in Ajax is not empty but in php $_POST and $_FILES is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi i have problem with ajax and formData

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
formData.append('image', $('inputFile')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: formData,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
}
});
```

in PHP i just print_r $_POST and $_FILES and it's empty.

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" enctype="multipart/data-form" method="POST">
<input type="file" id="inputFile" />
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

Headers are sent, request payload has the content but still $_POST or $_FILES are emptry.

Comment: Under what event are you sending the AJAX request?

Comment: i have function for this on button click

Comment: That could be your problem, hook to the `submit` event of the `form` instead

Comment: can you please provide the fiddle ?

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var file_data = $("#inputFile").prop("files")[0];
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("image", file_data);
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        url: url,
        data: ajaxData,
        error: function (result) {},
        success: function (result) {}
   });
```

You can get this as *$_FILES['image']* in php code

Comment: `formData.append('image', $('inputFile')[0].files[0]); ' do the same but still have $_FILES empty

Comment: I don't know where is problem. Before i do the same and it's still working now in new project have a problem with that. So i just change it to normal form but thanks for help

Comment: It might be problem with jquery. Once check that